# What does the "random element" do in Cellular Automata

Tags: procedural-generation, maps, random

I'm reading [this](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generate-random-cave-levels-using-cellular-automata--gamedev-9664) post on TutsPlus regarding procedural level generation using cellular automata. My question arises in this code snippet:

```
float chanceToStartAlive = 0.45f;

public boolean[][] initialiseMap(boolean[][] map){
    for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
        for(int y=0; y<height; y++){
            if(random() < chanceToStartAlive){
                map[x][y] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

In the first line, the author declares a float that represents 45%. This makes sense. However, the role of this is unclear to me. In this line:

```
if(random() < chanceToStartAlive)
```

A random number is being generated, and being tested if it's less than `0.45f`. Since it is an inequality, this expression can either return `true` or `false` correct?

How exactly is this percentage affecting this loop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume random() generates a random number between 0 and 1. This number will be less than 0.45 45% of the time.

I will use an example to show you why:
[image]

Let's say these rectangles represent a field, and it's raining. We would like to know how often the drops fall on the green part. For the rectangle on the top, the green part is half the total rectangle. So the drops will fall on the green part half of the time.

On the second retangle, the green part is 25% of the total so 25% of the drops will end up there.

In your case, this means that `map[x][y] = true;` will be called 45% of the time. In other words, 45% of the map booleans will be set to true.

`chanceToStartAlive` allow you to choose the percentage of *true* cells.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm still a little confused. How will the "number be less than 0.45 45% of the time"?

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand, but I would like confirmation. Is it because, the range of values that make the inequality true are |0 to 0.44| which are 45% of the total range |0 to 1.0| ?

Comment: I added details, I hope it helps. Yes you're right.

Comment: Maybe what you're missing is the implicit knowledge that `random()`'s domain is [0,1)